# Convert a Protege Ontology to Arff File for Weka

Tags: weka, ontology, protege, arff, protege4

I am currently working on an assignement composing of Weka and Protégé.

I have an enormous database with a lot of classes and subclasses, data properties and object properties.

They did provide me the database as a CSV file, which i used to create the ontology in Protégé, then entered each instances 1 per 1.

Then i converted the csv file to an arff file to work in Weka.

I tried to find some documentation but nothing on converting ontology work from Protégé to an arff file format...

**I would want to know if there is a possibility to parse, and convert the RDF/XML format of a Protégé Ontology to an .arff file to be used directly in Weka?**

My idea, maybe idealistic, is to reduce the amount of computation by already having multiple relations/inferred between the multiple classes in the datasets.

Has it been done before ? Is there a script that can be used to do this ?

Thank you for your help.